# Need to get user lists along Average in django while data in separate table

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.0

I am trying to get user list along with average login time

Model 1:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Model 2:

```
class History(models.Model):
    login_time = models.DateTimeField()
    logout_time = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKeyField(User, related_name="user_relation")
```

I need records in list of below format avg_logged_in_time will average of be (logout_time - login-time)

```
Name, email, avg_logged_in_time
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your queryset would look something like this. You can check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) for more info. Also, you can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) for info about the F Query Expressions.

```py
User.objects.values(
    'name', 'email', 'avg_logged_in_time'
).aggregate(
    avg_logged_in_time=Avg(
        F('history__logout_time') - F('history__login_time'), output_field=models.DateTimeField()
    )
)
```

Comment: actually situation is a bit different and I have to use Model User instead of History

Comment: I think you can still do the same. I've edited my answer. Since Django provides a reverse relationship, you can still access history fields from User.